# Unable to display the chart using Ionic3/2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, charts, highcharts, ionic2

Hi im trying to display the static data using the High charts and i am getting error 13 and i placed this

```
<div id="container" style="display: block;" ></div>
```

in html file and below is the data i am using to display chart

```
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';

ionViewDidLoad(){
    var myChart = HighCharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
      }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
      }]
    });
  }
```

Is there any better charting library for ionic for  displaying the charts other that chart.js

Comment: did you try with ng2-highcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package with angular2 named **[`angular2-highcharts`](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts)**

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
```

and options as,

```
class AppComponent {
    constructor() {

        this.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        };
    }
    options: Object;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/INuBc7bQDFvfOyfw7Kg6)**

Comment: Works on Angular 5? & What is the best chart library for ionic/angular

Comment: Which charting library is better?

Comment: with angular you can use ng2-charts or highcharts

Comment: marl of the answer helped

Comment: i am getting an error in the app module.ts saying that  ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'))' cannot find name require

Comment: you dont have to use require

Answer (score 1):

Check official [highcharts#typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts#typescript)

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-highcharts?ctl=1&embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts) demo

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import  Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage{
 @ViewChild("container", { read: ElementRef }) container: ElementRef;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    Highcharts.chart(this.container.nativeElement, {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
      }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
      }]
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but im getting this below error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: Check this line `@ViewChild("container", { read: ElementRef }) container: ElementRef;` ,error may be here. Please add you working demo where the error is.